# Formula for "Return" in FinancialData

Tags: curated-data, finance

After I get the data for the return, divident, and price of a stock with e.g.

```
FinancialData["BMY", "Return"] which gave -0.0153019
FinancialData["BMY", "Dividend"] which gave 0.41
FinancialData["BMY", "Close"] which gave 48.16
```

This stock lost $0.76.

What is the exact formula used by Mathematica that relates this daily return  to the closing price, dividend, and loss/gain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula Mathematica uses to calculate returns is

$$
Price_{t2}/Price_{t1}-1
$$

I am unable to replicate your return figure of `-0.0153019` as of Today in v13.1. Though I note that you ran this calculation on Mar23, 2019 a Saturday. Sometimes data from the previous day can be messy and take time to update

From the documentation of `FinancialData`:

*Note: FinancialData is intended for informational purposes only. Wolfram Research is not responsible for the accuracy or timeliness of any data.*

---

I am not sure if dividends affected your initial calculation but regardless, the formula above still holds

First using **Raw Prices**
*For historical data, properties such as "RawHigh", "RawLow", "RawClose" do not include any retroactive adjustments; i.e. they return values as they were reported on the trading day in question*

```
(*set data universe*)
stackExchangePostDate=DateObject["Mar 23, 2019"];
dataEnd=PreviousDate[stackExchangePostDate,"BusinessDay"];
dataStart=PreviousDate[dateEnd,"BusinessDay"];

(*get RAW data*)
{closeTS,returnTS}=FinancialData["BMY",{"RawClose","Return"},{dataStart,dataEnd}];

(*calculate return*)
close=QuantityMagnitude@Normal@Values@closeTS (* {48.91999816894531`,48.15999984741211`} *)
return=returnTS["Values"]//Normal (* {-0.015535534545781049`} *)
returnCalculatedManually=Ratios[close]-1  (* {-0.015535534545781049`} *)

(*check*)
return==returnCalculatedManually (* True *)
```

And using **Adjusted Prices**

*For historical data, properties such as "AdjustedHigh", "AdjustedLow", "AdjustedClose" are adjusted for stock splits, spin-offs, share repurchases and other corporate actions, as well as ordinary dividends.*

```
(*get ADJUSTED data*)
{closeTS,returnTS}=FinancialData["BMY",{"AdjustedClose","Return"},{dataStart,dataEnd}];

(*calculate return*)
close=QuantityMagnitude@Normal@Values@closeTS (* {44.195477831850305`,43.50887745922629`} *)
return=returnTS["Values"]//Normal (* {-0.015535534545781049`} *)
returnCalculatedManually=Ratios[close]-1  (* {-0.01553553454578116`} *)

(*check*)
return==returnCalculatedManually (* True *)
```